# How To Trigger Back Button To Go To Home Screen After Multiple Fragment Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

So I'm building an app that has navigation like this:

Login Fragment (Start Destination) -> Initial Settings Fragment -> Home Fragment.

In Login Fragment, there is a checking whether the user has logged in using SharedPreference. If so, user will be redirected to Initial Setting.

In Initial Setting Fragment, there is a checking whether the user has setup an account. If so, user will be redirected to Home Fragment.

What I want to ask is, for example, I'm logging to the app, and I will be redirected to Initial Setting Fragment. And because I have set up the account, the app redirect me to Home Fragment. So, how do I trigger back button to go to Home Screen instead of to previous fragment (initial fragment)?

What I understand so far is that I need to remove those Initial Fragment and Login Fragment from backstack. I tried to set up PopUp Behavior on my navigation.xml but still doesn't work.

Here's the navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.main.netwallet.login.LoginFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_registerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/registerFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_initialSettingFragment"
            app:destination="@id/initialSettingFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/registerFragment"
        android:name="com.main.netwallet.register.RegisterFragment"
        android:label="fragment_register"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_registerFragment_to_initialSettingFragment"
            app:destination="@id/initialSettingFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.main.netwallet.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/initialSettingFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/initialSettingFragment"
        android:name="com.main.netwallet.initialSetting.InitialSettingFragment"
        android:label="InitialSettingFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_initial_setting">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_initialSettingFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

So what do I need to change?

Thank you in advance

PS. I also have used findNavController.navigate(FragmentDirections.androidIdAction) instead of (R.id.fragmentId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Jatpack Navigation [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-navigation-backstack#3) is everithing explaied with example and exercise.

And also to give you a little summary you need clear your back stack as you navigate from fragment to fragment.
To say it in other words "don't track history".

Comment: Thank you. The link you gave's very useful!

Comment: You are welcome. I would appreciate marking question as accepted if it helped. Best of luck and don't give up!